# How to update a running service?

Tags: c#

Currently I have an application used to update my software, this is a standalone executable that's only job is to perform software updates.

When it is launched it copies itself from a \Binary\ to \Running\ folder and then executes itself in \Running\ to perform the work (so the copy in \Binary\ is never locked or in-use), in the case where it needs to update itself it simply updates the copy under \Binary\ so next time it is run the newer copy is executed and there is no issues. This process has worked fine for years ...

Now I need to make a change, I need to move this process to a SERVICE (so it can perform software updates as LocalSystem where it has Admin rights) - can I use the same model? Can a service, when it starts, copy itself from \Binary\ to \Running\ and run from the \Running\ folder at all times?

Otherwise, any suggestions on how I could update Service.exe?

Any advice, help, suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: You are asking about updating the updater executable, am i right?

Comment: Yes ... the Service.exe (that is used to update my software) itself can be updated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a project in the past, we used a two-phase update:

- first, a very very small simple program called Stub would check for updates to the actual updater (called CopyFiles).  If CopyFiles was newer on the server, it would get copied down.
- then, Stub would launch CopyFiles and terminate itself.
- CopyFiles could then update Stub if needed as well as all the main application files.
- CopyFiles would then launch the main application executable.

For your scenario, I can forsee two services running - one which is your actual application and another which monitors your \Binary folder.  That service, having Admin rights, can shut down the actual application service, copy the updates to \Running and then start the app service back up again.

Comment: Well - to make it less complicated - I have no issues with forcing a REBOOT when updating the Updater.exe service. So have a Stub.exe service that starts, checks if Updater.exe.new exists in \Binary\, copy it to \Running\ and then start the Updater.exe Service?

Would that be your recommendation (type thing)?

Comment: That does make it pretty easy.  There's a Win32 API method called MoveFileEx(), which has a pInvoke (Interop) signature here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/MoveFileEx.html and the flags definition here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/MoveFileFlags.html .  The flag you're interested in is MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT and your call will look like: NativeMethods.MoveFileEx(@"\Binary\Updater.exe", @"\Running\Updater.exe", MoveFileFlags.MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT);

Comment: And, once you've done that, you will likely want to schedule a reboot to happen at a certain time.  In your service which updates the executables, you can call the Task Scheduler API.  Couple of good references: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/taskschedulerlibrary.aspx .  The command you want to schedule is SHUTDOWN.EXE with it's various parameters.

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a separate Windows service that invokes your existing app? As long as your app doesn't have a GUI and doesn't assume its running under a user account (e.g. doesn't access HKCU registry keys), then that should work. Under Windows a child process inherits the security context of the parent process, so the standalone exe invoked from the service should run under the service account configured.

Comment: Then you loose control of the existing application - if the seperate windows service launches the updater.exe service then terminates (it would need to terminate so it could be updated by updater.exe) the how do I control updater.exe (stop/start/etc...)? How would the Service Manager handle it?

Comment: If the Windows service *just* runs the separate updater.exe, why does it need to change at all?  updater.exe can update itself like it currently does. The service just invokes it according to whatever logic you want - e.g. once a day at a predetermined time.

Comment: Obviously if you moved the intelligent update *into* the service, it would need to be updatable - I was suggesting a dumb service which just just invokes updater.exe.

Comment: I've learned that even the dumbess little tool may need to update one day and therefore you always need a plan/structure to do it - because once its out there your stuck.